# Connecting the STM32 blue pill to the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE (macOS)

Tags: macos, arduino, stm32, arduino-ide, st-link

I am using the Arduino IDE to program a STM32 blue pill using a St-link v2. To configure everithing I follwed few guides like [this one](https://www.luisllamas.es/programar-stm32-con-ide-de-arduino-y-st-link-v2/) and eventually I could get a successful upload and get the blinking  pin c13 example running.

My problem is that enven I am able to compile and upload, the Arduino IDE does not detect any port, so I cant use the Serial Monitor as it shows

*Not conected. Select a board and a port to connect automatically.*

And indeed, the IDE does not recognise a port for any configuration...

[image]

[image]

but it does show the stlinkv2 in the macOS system report

[image]

Does anybody know what Im missing here? Theres maybe other alternative to see code-promts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ST-LINK probe you have doesn't provide a virtual serial port functionality. It's a debugger/programmer using the SWD protocol.

I'm not familiar with using STM32 with Arduino framework, but in order to use `Serial` class of the Arduino framework, you probably need to access one of the hardware serial ports of STM32F103.

In this case, you need an external USB - Serial converter which works with 3.3 volts logic levels and connect it to the relevant serial port pins of your Blue Pill board.

Some ST-LINK models also provide embedded USB - Serial converter interface along with the SWD functionality. But even if you have one of those, you still need to physically connect ST-LINK serial pins into the Blue Pill serial pins.